# How to in javascript update inner object array with spread operator

Tags: javascript, angular, spread-syntax, ngrx-reducers

I have in my reducer for a store, need to update an inner array object value:

for:

```
export interface SiteState {
  site: Site;
}
```

and

```
export interface Site {
  id: number | null;
  uuid: string;
  subscriptions?: (SubscriptionI)[] | null;
}
```

and would like update the site->subscriptions[x] = action.payload

// edited with solution

```
function handle(state: SiteState, action: Successaction): SiteState {
  const sub = state.site.subscriptions.map( subs => {
    if (subs.uuid === action.payload.uuid) {
      return action.payload
    } else {
      return subs;
    }
  });
  const site = { site: {...state.site, subscriptions: sub} };
  return site
}
```

I tried the spread operator but he just push my new subscriptions into the root site,
si don"t know how write it for update the object SubscriptionI who is an array.

Comment: try this: `const site = {...state.site, subscription: [ ...state.subscription, ...action.payload]};`. Or try to use another structure, like Map or Set, if there are any keys and then update them by key.

Comment: In `subscriptions[x]` where is `x` comes from ?

Comment: Type '{ subscription: SubscriptionI; id?: number; uuid?: string; name: string;' is
not assignable to type 'SiteState'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'subscription' does not exist
in type 'SiteState'.

Comment: @RamiLoiferman the com from nowhere i still need filter or map by id, from the payload

Comment: You need to `return {site}` to match the `SiteState` return type.

Comment: ok perfect thanks to all works now updated with solution

Comment: You should definitely not use `filter`, use `map` instead.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to completely replace the subscriptions array then what you are doing is correct. However if you just want to add the whatever you have in action.payload to the subscriptions array than you need:

```
  const site = {...state.site, subscription**S**: [...state.site.subscription**S**, action.payload]};
```

Comment: not assignable to type 'SiteState', and 'subscription' does not exist in type 'SiteState'.

Comment: Yes your interface is called subscriptionS not subscription that is why in my answer you have the stars around the 'S'